# a Mean Value Theorem Proof

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Disclaimer: this is not homework for marks

Question: Does there exist a diﬀerentiable function $f$ with $f(0) = 2$, $f(2) = 5$, and $f'(x) ≤ 1$ for all $x ∈ (0,2)$? If not,why not?

My attempt (incomplete because I don't know what to do):
$c \in (0,2)$

$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(c)}{b - c}$

$f'(c) = \frac{f(2) - f(0)}{2 - 0}$

$f'(c) = \frac{5-2}{2}$

$f'(c) = \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Well, so what is the question? You showed that it is impossible. The derivative must be equal to $\frac{3}{2}$ at some point in $(0,2)$.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion. I just wanted to know how to write this as a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value theorem states that if $f$ is a differentiable on $[a,b]$, then there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ with $f'(c)={f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}$. Thus, for $f$ in this question, there would need to be a $c\in(0,2)$ with $f'(c)={f(2)-f(0)\over 2-0}={3\over 2}>1$, so there can't exist such a function.

Comment: +1. I was composing an answer along these lines, starting by saying that the OP's idea is correct but the "proof" is unacceptable (to me, as an instructor) because it's missing all the words that explain how the equations fit together to make an argument. You have provided the words.